# Sqlbulkcopy doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sqlbulkcopy

I have created a datatable and trying to insert that datatable through SqlBulkCopy but somehow it doesn't seem to work for me....

I got the error,

```
The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted
to type decimal of the specified target column.
```

My Datasource is,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpId", typeof(Int64)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FromDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ToDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DaysPresent", typeof(decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OpeningAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AdvanceDeducted", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RemainingAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SalaryGiven", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime)));

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(((HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("HiddenId")).Value);
            dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
            dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
            dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].FindControl("TxtDaysPresent")).Text);
            dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtOpeningAdv")).Text);
            dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[5].FindControl("TxtAdvanceDeducted")).Text);
            dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[6].FindControl("TxtClosingAdvance")).Text);
            dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)row.Cells[7].FindControl("TxtSalary")).Text);
            dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
    SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
    sbc.DestinationTableName = "SalaryDetails";
    sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
    sbc.Close();
```

And my destination Table looks like this,

[alt text http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/5448/mytable.jpg](http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/5448/mytable.jpg)

Comment: image has expired mate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify a column mapping, as you don't have the same number of columns in the DataTable and the destination table.

You can do it like this:

```
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("EmpId", "EmpId");
sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("FromDate", "FromDate");
// and so on, with the rest of the columns; and after that comes
sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
sbc.Close();
```

Comment: @treaschf how to add column mapping?

Comment: @treaschf `sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("EmpId", "EmpId");` is this what i want to do..